# Publish WEB2 project online or wait until is MVC framework ready?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, cakephp, publish

in the last 2 years I've studied `php` and `MySQL` in order to build my project. I come from `ActionScript3` and so `Object Oriented Programming`, but I'm an self-taught, and unfortunately I don't know the deepest parts of programmation.

Now the project I've written is near to the end and It could be published online, but It's all written in procedural `php` style, only with a class for the session and something.

All works fast and without problems (for what I can see), but if I need to add some functions to the site, like user board, add login with other accounts (facebook, openid, etc.), I think that would be difficult to be changed.

I know there are solutions like `cakephp`, `zend` and many other `MVC frameworks`, useful to optimize develop time, so I was just wondering if I should start with that base or I could pass to it in the future.

The current database is not so different from how it should be to be MVC ready, some things need to be changed and I don't know what exactly involve this, I don't know if It's possible to change the database structure in the future with millions of rows added (I hope!).

So my question is:

Should I publish my `web2` project online or should I wait to rewrite it `MVC framework` ready?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publish early to see if it works. Your project is worthless without users anyway. You can rewrite it behind the scenes in your testing environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually questioned this myself when taking old websites and wanting to convert them to cakePHP. When you first look at a decent size project like that, it can be overwhelming but once you crack into it you can actually have some fun with it.

Example: Since, building websites everyday can be tedious and monotonous, you can actually enjoy this migration process with some new techniques. I was able to convert a 9 table database to be MVC ready by writing a series of javascript regular expressions that process the data into the format that I needed.

It could take you a week or 2 to accomplish this but if you are looking to expand your skills, you might enjoy it.

Of course doing these kinds of processes with millions of table entries might be a bit much for javascript, but with the ability to write MVC apps in less than a week, you might have your site rebuilt in less than a month (MIGHT).

Good luck.

Comment: I'm trying to use cakephp but it making me crazy... inserting relational data isn't so simple if  you start for the first time, surely I could spend 1 month to refactory the project, but I'll need 1 year to learn cakephp well, for now I think I'll choose to build the project online without rewrite it. Thanks for the help!